# How to fix reversed arabic characters mixed with english in pl / SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, arabic, nls-lang

I have an oracle database and I have stored print message inside it contains Arabic and English characters in the same field just like عبر الرابط : (https\www.google.com)

Seeking your help to split the Arabic characters from English ones to reverse them. as the Arabic characters don't have specific positions in the field, start, end, or in the middle of the field.

What is needed is to make them display correctly in the same direction.

Comment: How about creating **two** separate *print message* columns? One would be used for Arabic text, and another for English. You'd populate one or both, depending on what that message represents.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; **your** query to display the sample data; which IDE are you using; your NLS settings and database character set; a detailed description of the problem (is it storing the text incorrectly or is it displaying incorrectly); and the expected output as I cannot replicate the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=90fbf42057d1d3b601162d501bd3df7b).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.